# StartActivity() lags by 2 sec when called from onPostExecute of Async task

Tags: android, android-asynctask, start-activity

I have a requirment where I have never ending list(list items gets the data from server) in MainActivity and on click of item I fetch details for that list item and show it in other Activity.

Now when async task is running for fetching list items user clicks on item then other async call gets placed and fetch the details for that list item.After details are fetched the Activity starts after a while.User can see the lag of starting activity.
Can any one suggest what can be done in this case.

Comment: More info please. Do both asynctasks run on the same executor? If so the second won't start until the first is finished...

Comment: No they are two different Async tasks.Both are executing simultaneously.

Comment: So opening the activity takes two seconds. Or did you mean to tell that executing an asynctask and then opening an activity takes two seconds in total? And how do you know the tasks run simultanuously?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason the item details are fetched from an other async task? You are already in a background thread, and the user is not likely to keep scrolling the list after click on an item.

If the fetching takes too much time, you might be better opening the new Activity immediately, only passing the item id in the intent. The Activity would then have the responsibility to fetch the details.

That way, the user see something is happening and your app will seems much more responsive.

Comment: yes, as details of the item needs to be displayed in otheractivty it is a need to fetch details first and then call startAcitvty :)

Comment: Is there a reason the other activity cannot fetch the details itself?

Comment: that activty shows only the details.If the activity fetch that details user will see the blank page which is not visibly nice

Comment: In my opinion this is better than nothing happening for 2 seconds. You could also pass the information of the list to the other activity since they are already loaded. That way they get displayed immediately, and load the rest while displaying a progress bar for example.